# Web Method accepting huge xml string

Tags: xml, web-services

I have a web service with just 1 Web method which will accept xml as string.

This web method is a function which will loop through data received and insert into sql server database in relevant tables.

When I try to consume this webservice which is on my machine from another vb.net application if the XMLstring is too huge I am getting a network error.

Is there a limit on the length of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the httpRuntime maxRequestLength to a higher max.